# AS3: MovieClip spawning x and y being overriden and replaced by RandomLoop (Adobe CC AS3)

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, flash, associative-array

I have a problem with my code in AS3 using OOP. I have created a loop which does the following:

- It loads 2 arrays, Position Array (posArray) and Ring Array (ringArray).
- It checks and loops the functions getRandomPosition and getRandomRing
- It returns the values from the functions and gives us the Array values.
- These position values include Id, X and Y. The Ring array values take MovieClips from the library.
- I create two variables called randRing and randPosition to determine which ring will be placed where.
- Thus I call on the function randRing to give me a randomly generated MovieClip of the three selections and add this to the stage (in GameLevel1.as)

Now, When I call on this function to addChild onto the gamestage. It only adds 3 rings for the three seperate ring Movieclips. This is not meant to happen. It needs to just randomly pick one of 8 locations and pick one of 3 rings to spawn on said location. Instead it keeps changing the position value of the rings.

(this program also checks if there's a ring already spawned on the location and tries to find another location if that is the case. However that's not where our problem is coming from).

Now for my question: Why is it overriding the values given to the movieclips instead of creating new movieclips? Changing the code from addChild(randRing) to addChild(new randRing) causes it to crash to not being called on inside the constructor (due to the while loop).

Our call on GameLevel1.as is like this :

```
    //Add rings to stage.
    var ring:ClassRingLoop2 = new ClassRingLoop2();
    trace("Ring in GameLevel: ", ring);
    backgroundLayer.addChild(ring);
```

followed by the ClassRingLoop2 (Version 1 was not working properly).

```
    package 
    {
    import flash.text.*;
    import flash.display.*;
    import flash.events.*;

    public class ClassRingLoop2 extends MovieClip
    {
    //8 different positions       (id, x, y,)
    public var posA:Array = new Array(1, 69, 506);
    public var posB:Array = new Array(2, 100, 545);
    public var posC:Array = new Array(3, 137, 400);
    public var posD:Array = new Array(4, 158, 500);
    public var posE:Array = new Array(5, 215, 405);
    public var posF:Array = new Array(6, 215, 480);
    public var posG:Array = new Array(7, 304, 437);
    public var posH:Array = new Array(8, 290, 500);

    //Ring from library
    public var ring1:ringClip1 = new ringClip1();
    public var ring2:ringClip2 = new ringClip2();
    public var ring3:ringClip3 = new ringClip3();

    //Add 8 positions to the array.
    public var posArray:Array = new Array(posA, posB, posC, posD, posE, posF, posG, posH);
    public var posOccArray:Array = new Array();

    //Add rings to Ringarray
    public var ringArray:Array = new Array(ring1, ring2, ring3);

    //Contructor
    public function ClassRingLoop2()
    {
        //Loop 8x
        var c:Number = 0;
        while(c<8)
        {
            trace("--------------------------------------");
            var randRing = getRandomRing();
            //trace ("In constructor: ", randRing);

            var randPosition = getRandomPosition();
            //trace(randPosition[0], randPosition[1], randPosition[2]);
            trace("Positie: ", randPosition[0]);

            //determining position of randRing
            randRing.x = randPosition[1];
            randRing.y = randPosition[2];

            //spawning of the ring
            trace("Ring: ", addChild(randRing));
            addChild(randRing);

            c++;
            trace("Count: ", c);
            trace("--------------------------------------");
            trace("  ");
        }

    }

    //Taking random value from posArray
    public function getRandomPosition()
    {
        //Random position of position array
        var pos:int = Math.floor(Math.random() * posArray.length);
        //Naming the Random position 'randPos'
        var randPos = posArray[pos];            
        //trace("Random position: ", randPos[0]);

        if(posOccArray.indexOf(randPos[0]) == -1) // if randPos[0] (positie ID) niet in posOccArray staat
        {
            //Push position ID in posOccArray
            posOccArray.push(randPos[0]);
            //trace("Occupied array: ", posOccArray);

            //Return random position
            return randPos;
        }
        else //if position ID is in OccArray
        {
            //trace("No, thanks. ", randPos[0], "position already occupied");

            //Repeat function until valid value is given.
            return getRandomPosition();
        }           
    }
    public function getRandomRing()
    {
        var ring:int = Math.floor(Math.random() * ringArray.length);
        var randomRing = ringArray[ring];

        //trace("In functie: ", randomRing);
        return randomRing;
    }
        }
    }
```

I hope someone is able to help us out.

Kind Regards,

Heerco / Veradux

Answer (score 0):

Did I get it right ?

> It needs to just randomly pick one of 8 locations and pick one of 3
>   rings to spawn on said location.

Does it mean, you just need one random ring on one random location? So visually, there will be only one ring on the stage ?

If the answer is yes, why do you need to loop it 8 times?
You can simply delete the while loop, and you'll get exactly what you want.

Let me know if I misunderstand anything.

** OR ... if you mean you want the ring to be put on all 8 location. **

Then you'll need to call "new ringClip#()" 8 times.

```
public function getRandomRing()
{
    var ring:int = Math.floor(Math.random() * ringArray.length);
    var randomRing;

    switch (ring) {
        case 0 : randomRing = new ringClip1(); break;
        case 1 : randomRing = new ringClip2(); break;
        case 2 : randomRing = new ringClip3(); break;
    }

    return randomRing;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, it's supposed to create a NEW ring on the stage position everytime it loops. So it should only spawn 1 ring out of 3 on 1 of 8 locations. BUT it should do the locations in a loop and decide a ring out of the ringarray. So in essence, it'll have 8 places with a different ring on each.